# What is the difference between "na" and "nicht"?

Tags: negation, particle

When do I use "na" or "nicht" in German?

For example, `na gut` vs `nicht gut`, is there a difference? Which is grammatical?

`Na klar` vs `nicht klar`, are both grammatical?

Comment: They aren't related at all. While, e.g., _nicht klar_ means _unclear_, _na klar_ is approximated by _of course!_ or _sure!_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The examples you listed have a different meaning. `na` is not a negation but an [interjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection).

`na klar` means: `sure`

while `na gut` means: `if it can't be helped` or something.

from [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/na):

> ein sehr nuancierter, kontextabhängiger, floskelhafter Ausdruck der Zustimmung, der  Überraschung, der Verwunderung, des Zweifels, der Skepsis, der Ablehnung, der Ungeduld, des Ärgers, der sanften Drohung, der Ermahnung, der Entrüstung, der Missbilligung; er dient weiterhin der Schaffung einer Denkpause oder Gesprächspause, um die Aufmerksamkeit, die Spannung zu erhöhen oder das Nachfolgende herauszustellen

Comment: Well, in spoken *Bairisch* and maybe other southern dialects "na" is used for the word "nein".

Comment: But it isn't _nicht_, and is pronounced in a different way (long _a_).

Comment: Bavarian "na" is just a homophone but has nothing to do with the word asked here.

Answer (score 3):

"na" isn't a negation. It doesn't mean "no" in any way. "na" doesn't change the meaning of what you say, it just changes the tone. It mostly acts like a reinforcement of its succeeding words. You can always leave it out, it's somewhat redundant.

"nicht" instead has a very clear semantic meaning, it negates the succeeding word.

Comment: sorry but i have to disagree on leaving it out... you can't leave out `na` in `na gut` because it significantly changes the meaning from `good` to `reluctant agreement`

Comment: @Vogel612: sounds like nitpicking, given that in this case you'd have to assign negativity to "oh" in English such as in "oh well", which conveys pretty much the same meaning as "na gut" does in German. It's a fair point, but "reluctant agreement" still isn't the same as an objection (which indeed could be filed under outright negativity).

Comment: I don't think that "na gut" is always reluctant. It comes down to how you say it and I have used "Na gut" in contexts where I agreed to a proposed alternative but I was totally fine for me. Also, I can say "gut" in a way, that it sounds very reluctant... maybe by adding the "exhale of discontent" or something.